# How do identify a new user using auth0-js WebAuth?

Tags: javascript, authentication, auth0, graphcool

I'm trying to keep things simple and using auth0-js WebAuth to authenticate users. However, as there is a redirect involved, I'm not in control of the sign-up functionality at that point.

My specific use-case is to call a `createUser` graphql mutation using Graphcool to create a user in my database, but I only want to do this if the user is a new user, obviously.

**MY QUESTION:** Using auth0-js, is it possible to identify if a user is a new or existing user in my client application after the redirect from Auth0 back to my client application (assuming authentication is successful)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two general approaches here, and both require you to **persist the Auth0 token in local storage** after receiving it. You can use a middleware for your GraphQL client that checks local storage for a token for every request and includes it as the `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header if present.

Let's now look at the two approaches.

### Always try to create the user

Trying to create the user using the `createUser` mutation as soon as receiving the token is a fairly simple approach. This is how the mutation looks like:

```
mutation signUp($token: String!) {
  createUser(authProvider: {
    auth0: {
      idToken: $token
    }
  }) {
    id
  }
}
```

Now, if the token is valid and matches the configuration of the Auth0 integration in Graphcool, there are two possible scenarios. Note, a token corresponds to a user if the `auth0UserId` it embeds matches.

- *there is already a registered user corresponding to the token*. In this case, a GraphQL error `Code 3023: CannotSignUpUserWithCredentialsExist` will be returned (compare with the [error reference documentation](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/simple-api/error-management-aecou7haj9/)). In your application you can catch this error to proceed normally.
- *there is no registered user yet corresponding to the token*. The `createUser` mutation will return `id` and all is good!

### Check if the user is already signed in

If you have a more elaborate sign up flow, you might want to redirect your users to a sign up form, which is not really possible with the first approach. Instead, we can check if the currently used token corresponds to a registered user before proceeding. You can use the `user` query to do that:

```
query {
  user {
    id
  }
}
```

Again, there are the same two scenarios as above:

- *there is already a registered user corresponding to the token*. In this case, a the query returns a `user` object with the corresponding user `id`. So we can proceed the flow in the app normally.
- *there is no registered user yet corresponding to the token*. The date returned from the `user` query will be null, so we need to call the `createUser` mutation, or switch to a sign up form or similar.

Compare this to [this FAQ article](https://www.graph.cool/docs/faq/graphcool-session-user-goij0cooqu/) in the Graphcool documentation.

Answer (score 2):

In that case, the simplest solution will be to use auth0 rule and use **context.stats.loginsCount** field to detect the user is new or not. 
https://auth0.com/docs/rules/references/context-object

You can add **context.stats.loginsCount** field value as a custom claim in the token using rule. Therefore, in your application, you can make a HTTP request to [/userinfo](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v9#extract-the-authresult-and-get-user-info) endpoint to get the token data.

```
function (user, context, callback) {

     const count=context.stats.loginsCount;
     context.idToken["http://mynamespace/logincounts"] = count;


  callback(null, user, context);
}
```

https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/adoption/scope-custom-claims

If the counts are equal to 1, create the user in your DB.